# Оптимизация/ускорение посимвольного перебора

Tags: python, комбинаторика, перебор

нужна помощь в оптимизации/ускорении следующей функции:

```
def per(gran):
    lst = [0]
    def perebor(current, limits, last, level):
        if level == len(limits):
            lst[0]=lst[0]+1
            return
        else:
            for i in range(last + 1, limits[level]):
                perebor(current | (1<<i), limits, i, level + 1)
    perebor(0,gran,-1,0)
    return lst[0]
```

Функция возвращает количество возможных расстановок по включенным друг в друга позициям, т.е. [3, 6, 7] будет означать что у нас 3 объекта, первый может занимать позиции 1-3, второй 1-6, третий 1-7 и возвращается соответствующее количество расстановок без повторений.
Проблема в том, что функция использует прямой посимвольный перебор, что делает вычисление больших чисел очень длительным. Есть ли способ ускорить или оптимизировать выполнение подобных операций?
В теории что-то такое возможно?
[image: произведение сумм]
Только с поправкой, что верхняя граница суммы не может быть больше "x", нижняя меньше 0. Ну и вместо 4 - "n". "С" - сочетания без повторений(x!/i!(x-i)!).

Comment: это ж комбинаторика, осталось найти или вывести формулу

Comment: вроде так: сортируем по возрастанию размера допустимого диапазона и  потом `x1 * (x2 - 1) * (x3 - 2)`

Comment: Здесь нет посимвольного перебора, однако с помощью битовых масок действительно перечисляются все распределения. Можно подумать об использовании динамического программирования.

Comment: x1 * (x2 - 1) * (x3 - 2) - это работало бы, если бы объекты различались, в этом случае они одинаковые и как-то повторения сокращать надо. Т.е. в общей области они работают как "сочетания без повторений"(если ничего не напутал).

Comment: Была идея через композицию числа(или что-то вроде того) искать, т.е. брать искомое  количество объектов(допустим 3 для 3ех интервалов) и раскладывать на композиции с нулями: 3 0 0, 2 1 0, 1 1 1, 1 2 0, 2 0 1. И от них через формулу сочетаний и сумму произведений получать нужное число. Но, непонятно будет ли этот способ эффективнее, второе но - еще непонятнее, как реализовывать такое чудо.

Comment: @hitandfun Я думал о методе включений-исключений (суммы-разности `C(n,k)`), но чего-то не учитывал, и результат не сходился. Кроме того, заполнял таблицу `количество единиц/крайняя позиция` - тоже не всё ясно было с заполнением

Comment: @MBo Не уверен как тут можно включения/исключения использовать, искать общую область у множества расстановок первого объекта со вторым и третьим?

Comment: А можно как-то на гпу эту функцию повесить? И поможет ли это?

Comment: @hitandfun Всего C(n,k) расстановок. Нужно отнять С(n-limits[0], k) тех, в которых первые limits[0] не содержат ничего и так далее. Однако пересечение случаев непросто получить. Табличный метод мне кажется более многообещающим.

Comment: @MBo Все, понял. Думал о чем-то похожем. Сформулировать универсальное правило не получилось.

Comment: А через "дерево" такое можно решить?(и имеет ли смысл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Табличный метод (квадратичная сложность n*k), где n - самая большая позиция (лимит), k- количество позиций (объектов).

В ячейке `T[row, col]` содержится количество расстановок `row+1` битов  - таких, что **последний** бит (в таблице - самый правый) стоит на месте `col`.

Для первой строки (один бит) понятно, что количество вариантов будет 1 для позиций, ограниченных первым лимитом.

Для следующих строк - количество вариантов в `T[row, col]` есть сумма значений в более левых ячейках вышележащей строки - поскольку мы можем поставить новый бит в позицию `col` для тех вариантов, последний бит которых левее `col`.

Сумма последнего ряда - искомое количество всех расстановок

Чтобы сумму не пересчитывать каждый раз, используется уже накопленная сумма из левой ячейки текущей строки.

```
def count_rasst(lst):
    n = lst[-1]
    k = len(lst)
    table  = [[0] * n for i in range(k)]
    for col in range(lst[0]):
        table[0][col] = 1
    for row in range(1, k):
        for col in range(row, lst[row]):
            table[row][col] = table[row][col-1] + table[row-1][col-1]
    #print(table)
    return(sum(table[-1]))
```

Для лимитов `[3,7,10]` будет 76 вариантов, и таблица выглядит как

```
 [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0], 
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,  0,  0,  0], 
  [0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 15, 15]]
```

Проверка моей переборной функцией и данной табличной:

```
 [11,23,37,59,97]   7632889   7632889
```